# Make: .DELETE_ON_ERROR for directory targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNU Make includes a special target called `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`. If this is included in your Makefile, Make will delete any target whose build sequence completes with a non-zero return status. This is helpful so that in subsequent invocations Make does not assume that the target has been properly built.

Here's a dummy example.

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

out.dat:    in.dat
            touch out.dat
            false
```

Because `false` gives a non-zero return value, the build is considered failed and Make deletes the `out.dat` target. This is the advertised and expected behavior. However, this behavior does not seem to be preserved when the target is a directory. Consider another dummy example.

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

outdir/:    in.dat
            mkdir outdir/
            false
```

In this case, the build fails again but Make does not remove the `outdir` directory. **Is there any way I can instruct Make to do this?**

Comment: I don't believe so but make doesn't handle directories as prerequisites at all well anyway so this isn't that big of a deal most of the time since you can't really depend on them meaning much anyway.

Comment: No you can't, at least not without modifying the GNU make source code.  Make will "unlink" the target and unlink only works on files: this is hardcoded in GNU make and not configurable.

Comment: You could perhaps put something in the recipe to remove the directory in case of failure, without using Make's `DELETE_ON_ERROR`. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: There's a bug submitted on it: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=16372

Comment: Note that a directory is basically like a file whose content is a map of name -> inode entries. So its mtime only changes when that map changes, i.e. when you add, remove, or move-replace a file or subdirectory inside it. Make is not designed to handle directories as target or prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, it is hard to use timestamps on directory. Few options:

- proxy target (%.dir)
- Atomic update using temporary folder.

Using proxy target, Makefile can be modified to incude a '%.done' target, which will embed the cleanup logic.

```
.PHONY: %.dir

outdir.dir:
    $(MAKE) outdir ; if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo CLEANUP $@ ; rm -rf dir ; false ; fi

outdir: ...  # as before
```

**And use the outdir.dir as a dependency**. Not elegant, but will get the work done. May be possible to to convert into a rule (disclaimer: I did not test this approach).

```
.PHONY %.dir

%.dir:
    $(MAKE) $* ; if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo CLEANUP $* ; rmd -rf $* ; false ; fi
```

Another variation is to change the outdir to add a "done" indicator file (if completed successfully), and use the proxy target to validate

```
%.dir:
    $(MAKE) $* ; if [ ! -f $*.done ] ; then rm -rf $* ; false ; fi

outdir:
   ... commands, any can fail.
   touch $*.done
```

As last resort (or first option, depending on your situation), consider, 'atomic' build for outdir - creating a temporary folder, and renaming it to outdir on success

```
outdir:
    rm -rf $@.new $@
    mkdir $@.new
    # Command to create outdir.new here
    mv $@.new $@
```